# Can SteamVR 2.2 be used to develop an app for Oculus Quest in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamvr, oculusquest

I am developing an app for Oculus Quest, but want to use the SteamVR 2.2 Input System instead of the Oculus OVR.  More specifically, I want to use the SteamVR hands and  SteamVR_Skeleton_Poser.

I tried just using the Interaction Example sample scene, but my hands are flickering all over the place!  If I switch the renderModelprefab to the hand prefab on the "Hand" component, it stops the flickering, but then I get the errors of not having the renderModel class.

My Quest also only shows a blank screen when I build and run the sample!?

Is there a way to get SteamVR working for Oculus Quest?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy natively for oculus quest(android), this will not work. You can have your app running on a PC and streamrender to oculus quest while using steamvr.